# Can we construct a ring of order $15$ without identity not isomorphic to $\mathbb{15}$?

Tags: ring-theory

I've proved any ring of order $15$ with identity is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ but what if the ring is of order $15$ with no identity element ? Can we construct a ring of order $15$ without identity not isomorphic to $\mathbb{15}$ ?

Comment: Hint: Let all products be $0$.

Comment: Yes I thought that but how to construct explicitly ?

Comment: I just did (there is only one choice for the additive group).

Answer (score 1):

The "trivial ring" example (with all products zero) has already been given, but you can also make one with nontrivial multiplication by taking $\Bbb Z_5$ with normal multiplication and $\Bbb Z_3$ with zero multiplication and form the product ring to get an example with nonzero multiplication.

You can also switch up which one uses zero multiplication, of course.